# How to check if user already taken the exam in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

After clicking the exam that the user has already taken it still continue to take the exam. **Not displaying an error that the user already taken the exam**
This is my code below and still cannot solve the problem so please help me. thank you.

Here is the database.

[image: Database]

```
<?php
    include("header.php");
    include("database.php");
    extract($_GET);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($rs)){
        $sql2 = 'select * from mst_result where login="'.$_GET[$user].'" and test_id="'.$_GET[$test].'"';
        $res = mysqli_query($cn, $sql2);
        if ($res && mysqli_num_rows() > 0){
            echo $user. "already taken the exam";
        }
        else{
            /*$sql2="SELECT * FROM mst_result WHERE login='".$loginid."' and test_id='".$test."'";
            $usernamecheck=mysqli_query($cn,$sql2);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($usernamecheck)>=1){
                echo $loginid." already taken the exam";
            }else{*/
            echo "<tr><td align=center ><a href=quiz.php?testid=$row[0]&subid=$subid><font size=4>$row[2]</font></a>";
        }
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: From the manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) 'Warning
Do not use extract() on untrusted data, like user input (e.g. $_GET, $_FILES).'

Comment: You really ought to use prepared statements with placeholders in your query, this code is wide open for attacks.

Comment: How do you determine that someone has already taken the exam? Are you sure that condition is written properly? What have you tried on your own to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You're counting your rows wrongly.

```
if ($res && mysqli_num_rows() > 0){
```

Should be this:

```
if ($res && mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){
```

mysqli_num_rows don't know what to count since it's not being fed the correct information.

Refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_num_rows.asp)